# How to add clickable link in a anchor indise php _e

Tags: php, html, anchor

How to add a clickable link in an anchor inside php _e function

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3 mr-sm-2">
        <input class="custom-control-input" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" name="terms">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rememberMe"><?php _e("Accept Terms & Conditions")?></label>
      </div>
```

We want to add a clickable link eg: " https://website.com/terms_and_policies " in " Accept Terms & Conditions "

Comment: You need to use the anchor tag explicitly <label class="custom-control-label" for="rememberMe"><a href="<?php echo 'https://website.com/terms_and_policies '; ?>"><?php _e("Accept Terms & Conditions")?></a></label>

Comment: Are you actually planning on implementing translations?